# Prove the set of all positive rational numbers in the form of $a/2$ for $a\in\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof

**Proof:** If $a\in\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered, since $a\ge 1$ and $1$ is the minimum element of $\mathbb{N}$, then $a/2\ge 1/2$. Furthermore, since $1/2$ is the minimum element of $a/2$, all positive rational numbers in the form $a/2$ is well-ordered.

**Is my Proof Correct? If not, what alternative can be used.**

Comment: What do you mean by saying that $a$ or ${a\over 2}$ is well-ordered? This is not a property of particular elements, but of sets.

Comment: @lisyarus I meant $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered. But the smallest element of $\mathbb{N}$ is $1$ and the smallest element of $\mathbb{N}/2$ is $1/2$. This is what I proved.

Comment: You need to show that EVERY subset of $\mathbb N/2$ has a smallest element, not just the whole set.

Comment: @D_S Even with the well-ordering principle? My book didn't go into detail of showing how subset and supersets of positive integers are well-ordered.

Comment: That's what it means for a set to be well ordered.  After all, the interval of real numbers $[0,\infty)$ is not well ordered: even though the set itself has a least element, $0$, a typical subset of $[0,\infty)$ does not have a least element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set is well ordered if every nonempty subset has a least element.

Your set is

$$X = \mathbb N/2 = \{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{2}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{4}{2}, \frac{5}{2}, ...\}.$$

You want to show that every nonempty subset $A$ of $X$ has a least element.

Already, you know that $\mathbb N$ is well ordered.

Isn't there a natural association between subsets of $\mathbb N$ and subsets of $\mathbb N/2$?  Namely, if you take subset of $\mathbb N/2$, and you double each element in the set, then you get a subset of $\mathbb N$.  Use this idea to prove that $A$ has a smallest element.

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordered? Assuming this, let $A=\left\{\dfrac{a}{2} \mid a\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$. Take $B\subseteq A$ such that $B\neq\emptyset$. Define $C=\{ 2z\mid z\in B\}$. Clearly $C\neq\emptyset$ since $B\neq\emptyset$. Moreover, if we take $z\in B$ then there exist $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $z=\dfrac{a}{2}$. Then $2z=a$. Thus $C\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ and therefore there exist $\min(C)$. Let $w=\min(C)$. Can you prove from here that $\dfrac{w}{2}=\min(B)$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to prove $w/2=\text{min}(B)$

Comment: Hint: as $w\in C\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ then $\dfrac{w}{2}\in B\subseteq A$. Take $r\in B$ arbitrary. Then $r=\dfrac{a}{2}$ for some $a\in\mathbb{N}$. Then we know that $a\in C$ (why?) and by definition $w\leq a$. Then $\dfrac{w}{2}\leq \dfrac{a}{2}=r$. Can you see it now?